# MFMessageComposeViewController continue previous conversation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Is it possible when I create a message compose view controller to a specific number that I am already engaging a conversation in iMessage or text, that I continue the conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.** That compose VC will not show conversation and there is no way to do it manually, but once you send message to recipient XY and then open Messages app, you can see the new message in conversation with XY. So iOS will automatically include this new message in existing conversation, but *not in this compose VC*.

Answer (score 1):

No...
The Mail application can create 'conversations' because it has a record of every sent/received message. But `MFMailComposeViewController` doesn't provide access to this history.

However, setting the same 'subject' title is enough to append the message to an existing conversation. (this is how 'conversation' are matched, rules may differ between mail clients : Google, Apple Mail, etc.. might have different heuristics to find 'conversations')

Comment: Question is about Message compose VC.

Comment: My mistake, sorry :) The mechanism seems even simpler in this case

Comment: Yes, with Messages conversations are based only on recipient.